# How can I connect LTE 4G USB MODEM to Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, usb-modem, modem

I need help to connect "**LTE 4G USB MODEM (Plug & Play Dongle Device)**" to my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

[Device Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C53Fr.jpg)

When I plug it to USB Port, it starts connecting/disconnecting problem.

And in Notification, it is showing
`activation network connection failed`

Video screenshot - [I am facing the problem](https://youtu.be/DwMUHqHF0-w).

From `lsusb` command -

**`Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1bbb:0195 T & A Mobile Phones`**

This device should be connected as Modem to my Computer and Wi-Fi HotSpot to other devices.

Thanks in advance.

FYI: I think, this dongle should be connected as Wired Connection.

It has IP address with username and password like Wifi Router.

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer, since it didn't help. But I'll leave this comment, so that if you ever figure out this problem, maybe you can let me know what you did, ok?

Comment: I didn't find any solution still now.

Answer (score 1):

the LTE dongle you have is a dual mode but only operates in Mobile APN mode or WIFI Dongle mode.
If you plug it into any powered USB socket you will be able to connect to it via your laptops wireless like any other wifi point. (192.168.100.1) any browser window.
user admin
password admin
oh wifi key is 12345667890
You can then configure the dongle and you should be able to sort out your connection issues. I hope...

Comment: My is 192.168.43.1